# Calling one stored procedure from another in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

In Oracle database,

Suppose there are two stored procedures
and stored procedure `sp1` is calling another stored procedure `sp2`

The question is:

Will the called `sp2` be able to access the `sp1's` `temp` table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose your mean: There is tmp table in database, sp1 filling the table, will be able sp2 to access (read or change) this data?

Yes it will. (If sp1 don't have "commit" before sp2 calling, of course).

Oracle Temporary Tables are used to store data for the duration of session or transaction.
Sp1 and sp2 both working in same session.

Comment: @KOMapOB.. thanks for the answer....i have a doubt in this...if sp1 has commit before sp2 calling and temp table has on commit preserve rows clause.......in this case..will the sp2 able to access the global temp table data of sp1 ?

Comment: The "preserve rows" are very importent words ) . If your table have this clause, then data will be deleted after session end. So "commit" in sp1 whill not delete it and sp2 will be able to access this data.

Comment: If your table don't have this clause, or your table have "ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS" clause, then data will be deleted after "commit" and sp2 will be unhappy.